# React создание нового state состояния в корневом компоненте зависящим от состояния другого элемента

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с состояниями в классовом компоненте, пока что нуб в React, [такой пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/class-component-ndduk?file=/src/App.js)

```js
   import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import users from "./data";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  //// Data about some user
  userId: users[0].id,
  userName: users[0].name,
  bonusesStatus: users[0].bonusesStatus
};
  }

  /// Почему если занести значение сюда.
  ///
  /// this.state.unavailableBonuses = Object.values(bonusesStatus).filter(function (el) {
  ///     return el.isAccess === false
  /// }).length
  ///
  /// То оно не сработает ?

  render() {
let bonusesStatus = this.state.bonusesStatus;

if (bonusesStatus !== undefined) {
  this.state.unavailableBonuses = Object.values(bonusesStatus).filter(
    function (el) {
      return el.isAccess === false;
    }
  ).length;
}

return (
  <div>number of unavailable bonuses - {this.state.unavailableBonuses}</div>
);
  }
}

export default App;
```

Имеются данные с сервера (`data`), на их основе мне в корневой компонент App необходимо сохранить состояние количества Недоступных бонусов `this.state.unavailableBonuses` оно может меняться в зависимости от изменений значения `isAccess` соответствующего бонуса. Вопрос - Почему если я пытаюсь создать состояние, до render() компилятор этого не разрешает (закомиченый код) ... Возможно ли просчет `unavailableBonuses` занести в общее хранилище `this.state` компонента App ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная причина в неправильном понимании стейта. Следует использовать [setState()](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) - единственно легальный способ в React для изменения стейта в классовом компоненте. Если говорить очень упрощенно то **React** должен знать когда состояние компонента меняется и менно вызывая предназначенный для этого метод мы сообщаем об ихменениях. Если копнуть чуть глубже то **state** это не просто свойство нашего класса это свойство **React.Component** которое мы можем проинициализирова в конструкторе как обычную переменную, но далее мы должны действовать по правилам **React**a. Попытка повлиять на **state** другими способами не гарантирует эффекта. Более того время применения **setState** так же выбирает **React**, мы лишь "*добавляем в очередь изменения в состоянии компонента*" вызывая этот метод.

Обновление можно организовать в методе [componentDidMount()](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), **наш код обязательно должен быть заключен в метод (раз мы работаем с классовым а не функциональным компонентом)**

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState((state) => { // получаем текущее состояние стейта
    let bonusesStatus = state.bonusesStatus;
    if (bonusesStatus !== undefined) {
      let unavailableBonuses = Object
        .values(bonusesStatus)
        .filter(el => el.isAccess === false)
        .length;
      return {...state, unavailableBonuses};  // меняем стейт         
    } else {
      return state // оставляем стейт без изменений
    }
  })
}
```